# how to use @Requestparam @RequestBody together in spring restful

Tags: spring, rest

how to use @Requestparam @RequestBody together in spring restful

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/upate")
@ResponseBody
public ModelAndView availableCheck(
        @RequestParam("key") String key, @RequestBody User user)
        throws Exception {
    //handle
    //
}
```

I want to update user by unique key,so I need request key paramer and the new user json object.
Advance thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There is some possible mistake: if you return a `ModelAndView` then it is highly unlikely that you want to be it the ResponseBody, therefore remove `@ResponseBody`.

---

The other problem is that RespondeBody is for strings. It mean put the Body string in this variable.
So it your `user` is the command object populated by some form, then just remove the `@RequestBody` annotation

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/upate")
public ModelAndView availableCheck(
        @RequestParam("key") String key, User user)
        throws Exception {
    //handle
    //
}
```

Comment: Then do not return a ModelAndView, return your object instead.